MobaXterm: How to configure proxy for jump host
I'm trying to configure and save a session which connects to a server via an ssh jump host which requires specific proxy settings.
I'm able to configure proxy for the end server but not for the jump host.
Does anyone know how to configure proxy for jump host?

